# Clone function and addEventListener in button inside

Tags: javascript

I need to clone a div that contains an input file, and within the clone, there is a button to delete the created clone.
My problem is that once the clone is created I cannot add the function on the button to delete the clone.
The function does not work. Where am I wrong?

```js
if (document.querySelector('.clona-input-file') !== null) {
    var clonaInputFile = document.querySelector('.clona-input-file');
    clonaInputFile.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var RowDaClonare = document.querySelector('#row-da-clonare');
        var clone = RowDaClonare.cloneNode(true);
        clone.children[0].lastElementChild.value = '';
        clone.id = 'row-da-clonare-' + Date.now();
        RowDaClonare.after(clone);

        var _buttonDel = document.createElement("button");
        _buttonDel.id = 'cancellaInputClone';
        _buttonDel.type = 'button';
        _buttonDel.setAttribute("data-id-da-eliminare", clone.id);
        _buttonDel.classList.add("btn");
        _buttonDel.classList.add("btn-danger");
        _buttonDel.classList.add("cancellaInputClone");
        _buttonDel.innerHTML = '<i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i>';
        clone.appendChild(_buttonDel);
    });
}

var cloneSet = document.querySelectorAll(".cancellaInputClone");
for (var i = 0; i < cloneSet.length; i++) {
    cloneSet[i].addEventListener('click', fx_button);
}

function fx_button() {
    console.log(this)
}
```

Comment: when the click event is done, only the code in the callback function get executed. The buttons won't work because they don't exist when the cloneSet loop is run.

Comment: This I know. I can't find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're attempting to bind event handlers to elements which don't yet exist in the DOM. This can be addressed by delegating your event handlers to parent elements which do exist when the DOM loads, and interrogating the events to see if they were raised by the elements you created.

In addition there's some other issues in your code to address:

Firstly, don't use `id` attributes in dynamic content. It makes your logic more complex than it needs to be. Use classes instead, and relate elements to each other using DOM traversal methods, such as `closest()`.

Secondly, use `querySelector()` to find the child element, not children/index accessors. It's more robust.

Lastly, you can provide multiple separate class names to `classList.add()` to save you having to call it repeatedly.

With that said, try this working example:

```js
let cloneButton = document.querySelector('.clona-input-file');
if (cloneButton) {
  cloneButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let rowDaClonare = document.querySelector('.row-da-clonare'); // querySelector will return first match only
    let clone = rowDaClonare.cloneNode(true);
    clone.querySelector('input').value = '';
    rowDaClonare.after(clone);

    let buttonDel = document.createElement("button");
    buttonDel.type = 'button';
    buttonDel.classList.add("btn", "btn-danger", "cancellaInputClone");
    clone.appendChild(buttonDel);
    
    let icon = document.createElement('i');
    icon.classList.add('bi', 'bi-trash-fill');
    buttonDel.appendChild(icon);
  });
}

// icon click handler delegated to the .container element
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', e => {
  let el = e.target;

  if (!el.classList.contains('cancellaInputClone') && !el.closest('button')?.classList.contains('cancellaInputClone'))
    return;

  el.closest('.row-da-clonare').remove();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<div class="container">
  <button class="clona-input-file">Clone</button>
  <div class="row-da-clonare">
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
      <input type="text" class="foo" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understood everything. I am not convinced to use `document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', e => {})`, do you have alternatives to offer me?
Thank you very much for the solution to my problem

Comment: @user2077311 ... alternatives — `e => { ... }` can be rewritten as `function(e) { ... }` so `.addEventListener('click', function(e) { ... }` as seen in Rory's earlier `cloneButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) { ... })` on the 3rd line of the example. I currently tend to do what Rory did; use `function(e)` for longer functions and `e => { ... }` for shorter functions.

Comment: I was wrong in writing, sorry. I wanted to ask you for an alternative to insert addEventListener on the button remove to be able to delete the div, instead of inserting addEventListener on the .container. Always if there are alternatives :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, it looks like the `button` is created only when the `clonaInputFile` is clicked, but the `querySelectorAll` and  loop and `addEventListener` executes right after you registered the callback for the `clonaInputFil`. So now there is no button you are querying, and the `cloneSet` should be empty, if you haven't created before.

Try log out the length of `cloneSet`. If it is 0, I recommend you to put the `addEventListener('click', fx_button);` right after the creation of that button.

Comment: I tried to insert the function after creating the button, but not work